# What is the equivalent of Visual Basic Type in Android Java

Tags: java, eclipse, basic

This has to the simplest question on stackOverflow, but I am a complete beginner; sorry.

Can anyone tell me how to declare a custom Type.

In VB, I would do:

```
Private Type CustomPoint
    Dx as Single
    Dy as Single
    Dz as Single
    Vector as Single
End Type
```

How would I do the same on Eclipse?  Do I need to create a new class for this?

Thank a lot for helping!

Comment: Java uses Classes ...

Answer (score 2):

If you are asking what the `Java` class definition would look like, then consider the following:

```
public class CustomPoint {
    // Object fields
    float dX;
    float dY;
    float dZ;
    float vector;
    public CustomPoint() {}

//// CustomPoint methods
}
```

Comment: #ErstwhileIII, did you mean to close the bracket in the end ?

Comment: Yes, I thought this was the case;  my final question would be do I need to add this in a new Class file?  I am just thinking that If I need to include another Class (e.g. vector is one with direction/value held separately), do I need a new class file?  I am be talking complete nonsense here...

Answer (score 0):

Visual basic Types can be seen more as C's structs, in java (since is OOP) you can create a class to do same, something like this:

```
class CustomPoint{
    float Dx;
    float Dy;
    float Dz;
    float vector;

    public CustomPoint(float x, float y, float z, float v){
        Dx = x;
        Dy = y;
        Dz = z;
        vector = v;
    }

}
```

Comment: Java requires types also in ct.

Comment: public CustomPoint(float x, float y, float z, float v) { ... }

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CustomPoint {
    private float dx;
    private float dy;
    private float dz;
    private float vector;
    
    public CustomPoint(float dx, float dy, float dz, float vector) {
        this.dx = dx;
        this.dy = dy;
        this.dz = dz;
        this.vector = vector;
    }
    
    public float getDx() {
        return dx;
    }
    
    public void setDx(float dx) {
        this.dx = dx;
    }
    
    public float getDy() {
        return dy;
    }
    
    public void setDy(float dy) {
        this.dy = dy;
    }
    
    public float getDz() {
        return dz;
    }
    
    public void setDz(float dz) {
        this.dz = dz;
    }
    
    public float getVector() {
        return vector;
    }
    
    public void setVector(float vector) {
        this.vector = vector;
    }
}
```